# while Converting from JSON into object parameter, i have to handle list within a list -Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code skeleton.

```
public interface IAdmin
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public List<IUserName> UserNameList { get; set; }
}

[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void UpdatePerson([FromBody]List<IAdmin> AdminList)
{
 // etc.
}
```

As one can see , i have list of interfaces that i prefer to inject instead of using concrete classes.Unfortunately it is not allowing conversion of json into List(Iadmin) in the post method because of the List (IUsername) member.

If i use concrete classes like list(CUserName) and list(admin) its working though!

for interfaces, which i want to be injected through unity,it is failing. List(IUserName) .

Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a custom model binder for this.

Comment: That is by design. only way to get around that is to create a custom model binder.

Comment: I am not truly experienced in web api..i have read mvc theory to an extent..so that's the reason i was wondering about options..sort of aware custom binder or json converter was the answer